# Firebase.failed() returns 0 after Firebase.begin(), but returns 1 while reading or writing from/to firebase from ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, iot

The program was running fine, a few days ago, but now it just wouldn't read/write to the database. I'm running on ArduinoJson 5.13.5 and using FirebaseArduino library. I have set all the rules to true, would love to know how to debug this error. Also Firebase.error() does not give any output at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Firebase's fingerprint has changed recently and has caused the above issue!

from here get [the latest finger print](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/issues/476#issuecomment-591931886) and change it in the `...\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient.h`

In the file mentioned above: update the value of `static const char kFirebaseFingerprint[]` to the new one mentioned above.

P.S. One issue going forward for me(planing on implementing it on a long term basis) is how to be ahead of this issue in the future, so that I can get the data uninterrupted!

Comment: It is OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem.